# Mysql Connecion to visual Basic

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to setup the connection to a Mysql database. However I am getting a user error saying that:

```
WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe Error: 0 : Access denied for user 'Root'@'myiphere' (using password: YES)
```

A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

I have used this....

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON permissionsex.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

But the error is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error message I can see you're using the username `Root` but you granted rights to `root`. Mind the lower-case versus upper-case r.